# VSS "Shared" Files and Perforce

Tags: version-control, perforce, visual-sourcesafe

we are trying to change our vcs from Visual sourcesafe to Perforce, there is a nice feature in Sourcesafe for sharing same file btw. diffrent projects so you just need to change the master file and all other linked files are upto date after that. Is there any possibilityto achive the same effect in perfroce??

P.s. i ve already read the most of topics in the internet about this issue, even this http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/VSS-Shared-Files-and-Perforce

but it didn't realy work!

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you could give more details about exactly what you're trying to accomplish, or more details about exactly what things you've tried and how they didn't work?

Comment: i talked with Perforce so they told me that the only way to achieve a same effect as VSS-"Shared-files", is to use the Branch-&-Merge-Concept, so i have to update each Branch manually. So you need time to get used to it, but anyway thanks for your replay.